# Multiple Controls to PostBackTrigger's ControlId property inside a single update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, triggers, updatepanel

Hai guys,

Is it possible to add multiple controls(Buttons) to PostBackTrigger's ControlId property inside a single update panel....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What if you do in this way...?

```
  <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" />
    </Triggers>
```